Locating Bitcoin with only seed phrase
I purchased Bitcoin back in 2018. I have no record or recollection of how it was stored, but I do know it was never transferred to a physical wallet. At one point I was trading via an online exchange on my phone, but I can no longer log onto to any of the crypto apps I have on my phone from back then (and many of them no longer exist in the app store). I do however have the 12-word seed phrase. Is there any way I can access the BTC with this alone?
Any assistance much appreciated.
Thanks!
Miles

This question is similar to: Why is this 12-word mnemonic deemed invalid by multiple wallets?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also see I forgot which software I created my wallet with. How can I recover from a 12 word seed phrase?
